# Get Back List Item Control From Item Template WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, templates

I bind my list View with user controls as below,

```html
<ListView Grid.Row="2" Name="lvItems">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <my1:ucItem Name="li"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

That user control has local storage value that user will input at run time. I don't want two way binding because, at run time that user control add another value other than user control is showing. I set up some get method to get back value stored in user control. How can I get back that user control, lvItems.Items is just return Object List I bind to it, not my User Control. Is there a way to get back that generated User Control List.

for example, i want to read back ListView Items like that,

```
foreach(UserControl uc in lvItems.Items){//Do Something}
```

Comment: Do you want `lvItems` ItemSource in your UserControl `ucItem`?

Comment: no, Get back UserControl from lvItems Item Source. For example,
foreach(Usercontrol uc in lvItems.Items)
{}
But, it doesn't work like that.

Comment: Why would you do that? why do you need to iterate over the user controls for

Comment: @Amit
My UserControl Contains, 4 column
Image Column, 
Name,
Nested Item List (Grid),
Add Button column 

I Bind to main page this usercontrol.

When Add Button in usercontrol is clicked, it popup Another window,
and you can fill another information like remark, qty and others.
When finishing that popup window, it save back new data to that usercontrol.

But to save that new data to database, I need to retrieve that data. So
^_^

Comment: You should use DatBinding inside your usercontrol. and Bind the data to a ViewModel which will later on save the data tot he DataBase.

Comment: @Amit you mean, programatically create usercontrol and bind it to listview?

Comment: @Sinon No. Bind your ListView to a List of ViewModels. and create a DataTemplate for that viewmodel so the ListView will show it for each ViewModel in the List here is an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: And I make it so that It won't save data, unless save button at main form is clicked!

Comment: @Amit ok, I will check it!

Answer (score 1):

@Amit is right in the comments, you should really use MVVM and a data binding approach. That said, if you are determined to do it the other way, this extension method should help:

```
public static class ItemsControlExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TElement> GetElementsOfType<TElement>(
        this ItemsControl itemsControl, string named)
        where TElement : FrameworkElement
    {
        ItemContainerGenerator generator = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator;

        return
            from object item in itemsControl.Items
            let container = generator.ContainerFromItem(item)
            let element = GetDescendantByName(container as FrameworkElement, named)
            where element != null
            select (TElement) element;
    }

    static FrameworkElement GetDescendantByName(FrameworkElement element,
        string elementName)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (element.Name == elementName)
        {
            return element;
        }

        element.ApplyTemplate();

        FrameworkElement match = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as FrameworkElement;
            match = GetDescendantByName(child, elementName);

            if (match != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        return match;
    }
}
```

Usage would be like this:

```
foreach (UserControl uc in lvItems.GetElementsOfType<UserControl>(named: "li"))
{
    // do something with 'uc'
}
```

The `GetDescendantByName` method is based on one by Dr WPF from this blog post: [ItemsControl: 'G' is for Generator](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/07/20/itemscontrol-g-is-for-generator/). In fact, that whole series of blog posts about how the `ItemsControl` works is well worth a read: [Dr WPF: ItemsControl: A to Z](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/).